# Generating an array of arrays that when added equals a given number

Tags: javascript

i'm working on a bigger problem but am a little stuck on a certain issue. Hopefully, I can explain it clearly! I am looking to generate an array of arrays where each individual array has elements then when added together equal a certain number. An example would be:

target = 4

solution : [[1,1,1,1], [1,1,2], [2,2], [1,3], [4]]

edit: to make the question more clear, the solution should contain every possible combination of positive integers that will equal the target

Comment: What do you have so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: What input exactly you have and what target represent length of solution array ?.

Comment: Ah. I'm guessing that you're specifically interested in generating all possible combinations that will add up to the target. I think that is the part that most folks are missing. Care to add it to your question? This is more of an algorithm question than code.

Comment: It's also a common homework question. So common, I'm sure it's been asked before...

Comment: We like to see attempts at homework problems before answering them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach and loop from the last found item or one and call the function until no more values are to disperse.

```js
function x(count) {
    function iter(left, right) {
        if (!left) return result.push(right);

        for (var i = right[right.length - 1] || 1; i <= left; i++)
            iter(left - i, [...right, i]);
    }

    var result = []
    iter(count, []);
    return result;
}

x(4).map(a => console.log(...a));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what language you were working in. Also, it's general StackOverflow etiquette to show what you have already tried an what exact step you got stuck on. That said, here is some Python code that does what you want.

This problem is easy to solve as a recursive function. If you have some number `n`, the first number in a list of sums of `n` could be any number between `1` and `n`. Call that number `i`. Once it's picked, the rest of the list should sum to `n - i`. So just make a recursive function that adds up the results for all `i`'s that are less than `n` and all the results for each of the solutions to `n-i`.

```py
def get_sum_components(n):
    # ignore negatives
    if n <= 0:
        raise ValueError("n must be a positive int")

    # The only way to sum to 1 is [1]. This is the base case
    if n == 1:
        return [[1]]

    results = []
    # imagine that the first number in the list of sum components was i
    for i in range(1, n):
        remainder = n - i
        # get_sum_components(remainder) will return a list of solutions for n-i
        for result in get_sum_components(remainder):
            # don't forget to add i back to the beginning so they sum to n
            result = [i] + result
            results.append(result)

    # lastly, just the number itself is always an answer
    results.append([n])

    return results


print(get_sum_components(4))
# gives [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [4]]
```

If you don't care about order, this will create some duplicates (like `[1, 3]`, `[3, 1]`). It should be easy to filter those out, though. (Just sort all the lists and then use a dict/set to remove duplicates)